# Remove Text From Columns When Another Column Has "Yes"

Tags: excel, vba

i have the below macro which removes values in column H when column I has a "Yes" in. is there a way to change this into an automatic VBA that runs in the background?

```
Sub Remove_Column_H_Values()'
' Remove_Column_H_Values Macro
'


'
 Application.Goto Reference:="R7C9"
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table11").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
 "<>"
 Application.Goto Reference:="R7C8"
 Range("H8").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.ClearContents
 Application.Goto Reference:="R7C9"
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table11").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8
 Range("I8").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a button to your Sheet with this code.

```
Sub Remove_Column_H_Values()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100 'depends on how long your Values go
    If Yoursheet.Cells(i, 9) = "Yes" Then
        Yoursheet.Cells(i, 8) = ""
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Automatic, after Typing Yes in column I:
(In the sheet-module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 9 And UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then Target.Offset(, -1) = Empty
End Sub
```